# Unable to debug python function for churn_flag and post_churn_billing_flag

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the dataset for reference :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data from the provided dataset
data = {
    'Dealers_code': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4,4, 4, 4, 4],
    'Date': ['01-06-2020', '01-07-2020', '01-08-2020', '01-09-2020', '01-09-2021', '01-10-2021', '01-12-2021', '01-06-2022', '01-07-2022', '01-12-2022', '01-01-2023', '01-02-2023', '01-03-2023', '01-05-2023', '01-06-2023', '01-07-2023'],
    'Volume': [0, 52, 0, 28, 0, 98, 55.55, 0, 56, 70, 77.5, 0, 3, 0, 31, 8],
    'Zone': ['ODC', 'ODC', 'ODC', 'ODC', 'ODC', 'ODC', 'ODC', 'WBN', 'WBN', 'KL1', 'KL1', 'KL1', 'KL1', 'KL1', 'KL1', 'KL1'],
    'State': [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 3, 3, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
    'Dealer_cat': ['Gold', 'Platenum', 'Silver', 'Others', 'Gold', 'Platenum', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Gold', 'Platenum', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platenum', 'Silver', 'Others', 'Others']
}

#Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Unable to debug python function for churn_flag and post_churn_billing_flag.

'churn_flag' will be set to 0 for the first row of each dealer, and flagging will start whenever the first non-null 'Volume' appears for each dealer. The 'churn_flag' will also be set to 1 for rows where 'Volume' is null

```
# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

# Sort the dataframe by 'Dealers_code' and 'Date' to ensure the data is in chronological order
df.sort_values(['Dealers_code', 'Date'], inplace=True)

# Create the 'churn_flag' column and initialize it with 0
df['churn_flag'] = 0

# Find the index of the first non-null 'Volume' for each dealer and update the 'churn_flag'
def update_churn_flag(group):
    non_null_volume_idx = group['Volume'].ne(0).idxmax()
    if pd.notnull(non_null_volume_idx):
        group.loc[non_null_volume_idx:, 'churn_flag'] = 1
    return group

df = df.groupby('Dealers_code').apply(update_churn_flag)

# Create the 'Post_churn_billing' column
df['Post_churn_billing'] = 0

# Find the index of churn_flag being 1, and if the next row has a non-null 'Volume', set 'Post_churn_billing' to 1
def update_post_churn_billing(group):
    churn_flag_idx = group[group['churn_flag'] == 1].index
    for idx in churn_flag_idx:
        next_idx = idx + 1
        if next_idx < len(group) and pd.notnull(group.loc[next_idx, 'Volume']):
            group.loc[next_idx, 'Post_churn_billing'] = 1
    return group

df = df.groupby('Dealers_code').apply(update_post_churn_billing)

# Display the updated dataframe with the new 'Post_churn_billing' feature
print(df)
```

Desired output is :

```
 Dealers_code       Date  Volume Zone  State Dealer_cat  churn_flag  Post_churn_billing
7        1 2022-06-01    0.00  WBN      3       Gold           0                   0
8        1 2022-07-01   56.00  WBN      3       Gold           0                   0
9       2 2022-12-01   70.00  KL1     11   Platenum           0                   0
10      2 2023-01-01   77.50  KL1     11     Silver           0                   0
11      2 2023-02-01    0.00  KL1     11       Gold           1                   0
12      2 2023-03-01    3.00  KL1     11   Platenum           0                   0
13      2 2023-05-01    0.00  KL1     11     Silver           1                   0
14      2 2023-06-01   31.00  KL1     11     Others           0                   1
15      2 2023-07-01    8.00  KL1     11     Others           0                   0
0       3 2020-06-01    0.00  ODC     18       Gold            0                   0
1       3 2020-07-01   52.00  ODC     18   Platenum            0                   0
2       3 2020-08-01    0.00  ODC     18     Silver            1                   0
3       3 2020-09-01   28.00  ODC     18     Others            0                   1
4       3 2021-09-01    0.00  ODC     18       Gold            1                   0
5       3 2021-10-01   98.00  ODC     18   Platenum            0                   0
6       3 2021-12-01   55.55  ODC     18     Silver            0                   0
```

Comment: "The 'churn_flag' will also be set to 1 for rows where 'Volume' is null" did you mean where `Volume` is zero? You do not have any null values in the Volume field.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Where the volume is null make the churn_flag 1. however flag=1 logic is a bit complicated. first you need to find the first volume which is not null  basis on the Dealers_code. post that only the churn flag will be done. prior to that will be treated as 0. And for  Post_churn_billing check the churn_flag=1 and check the next row where volume is not null. if it is not null, flag to 1. Hope my explanation is understandable. you can refer to the output I shared

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think your problem is with this line of code right here:
`group.loc[non_null_volume_idx:, 'churn_flag'] = 1`

It is very subtle, and I didn't notice this until I had played around with it a lot, but essentially you accidentally introduced a slice notation. What this code does is modify the index you need, and all of the items at indexes after this item in the group. I think changing this line to the below should hopefully solve your problem.

`group.loc[non_null_volume_idx, 'churn_flag'] = 1`

Leave a comment below if I misunderstood anything, and I'll try to figure it out!